# Array Difference, nested For Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] !== b[j]) {
                result.push(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(arrayDiff([1,2,2,3], [1])); // output: [2,2,3]
console.log(arrayDiff([1,2,2,3], [1,2])); // output: [1,2,2,3,3] // desired output: [3]
```

Trying to solve Array Difference, multiple items inside 'b' causing unwanted output.

Comment: Please check your question again

Comment: Consider providing the input and desired output as well.

Comment: What is the "unwanted output"? I suggest that you add console.log or alert statements to provide feedback on what the JavaScript code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

#### Consider using a `Set` and `Array#filter`.

```js
const 
  arr1 = [1, 5, 3, 7, 9],
  arr2 = [5, 1, 10, 13],
  s = new Set(arr2),
  res = arr1.filter((a) => !s.has(a));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Worth noting will only work for arrays of primitives. Not known what OP's arrays contain

Comment: @charlietfl Agreed! But the `Set` can be easily modified for more complex types.

Comment: I wouldn't say "**easily** modified". It *can* be but whether it's easy is a different matter. It depends on whether you can derive a  unique value from the object or a unique combination of values. That is not always going to be the case.